# Qlik Sense : Editing User Access

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I am new to Qlik Sense and has been assigned task to divide users into two sets.

**User Set 1 :** 
These users can Create App, Load data, Create data models and create sheets over data model.

**User Set 2 :** 
These users can only Create and view sheets over data model or already created App.

We have access to QMC and have enough token.

Any help or redirection to proper knowledge source is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/3.1/Subsystems/ManagementConsole/Content/provide-users-with-access-using-user-types.htm

Define a custom property with the user role you want:

Developer: is allowed to create apps, sheets, stories, objects and can use and create data connections.
Contributor: is allowed to create stories and sheets for published apps but is not allowed to create new apps.
Consumer: can only consume and is not allowed to create content.

A developer can create apps and modify connections and a contributor can only create private stories or sheets based off a developer's app.

Once you've defined a custom property with one of these access roles click the users page in QMC and then you can assign a security rule to your users based on this custom property.

Load data rights can be defined in a separate section access section of the script within the app. The owner of the app has to modify this.